# Нужно ли разделять интерфейсы и абстрактные классы в С++

Tags: c++, ооп, интерфейс

Как известно, отдельных языковых средств для объявления интерфейсов в С++, а их роль могут выполнять абстрактные классы.
Но с идеологической точки зрения интерфейсы и абстрактные классы являются довольно разными сущностями. Интерфейсы описывают некий контракт того, как можно взаимодействовать с классом. Абстрактные классы являются корнем иерархии классов, используются для полиморфизма в духе

```
AbstractSuperClass* a = new SubClass;
```

и могут просто реализовывать общий функционал.

Нужно ли, программируя на С++, разделять эти понятия и писать интерфейсы, как в Java/C#? Или можно(нужно?) смешивать и использовать только абстрактные классы?

Comment: Но в C++, насколько мне помнится, нету интерфейсов, так что их в любом случае придётся эмулировать абстрактными классами, разве нет? Что вы имеете в виду под «разделять»?

Comment: @VladD, как раз таки эмулировать. Т.е. использовать отдельный абрактный класс для "описания контрактов"(интерфейс), и отдельный - для иерархии классов и полиморфизма(собственно сам абстрактный класс).
Собственно есть ли в этом смысл? Или в плюсах так не делают?

Comment: А, понял вопрос. Ну, я бы разделил, да, для того, чтобы отделить логику контракта от логики имплементации. Но я не пишу на C++, так что подождём, что скажут гуру.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C#/Java нет множественного наследования классов, но есть множественное наследование интерфейсов. Поэтому в этих языках разделять интерфейсы и абстрактные классы приходится волей-неволей.

В С++ такого ограничения нет, поэтому нет особой надобности в выделении отдельного понятия "интерфейс", и отделения его от абстрактного класса. Интерфейсом может служить любой абстрактный класс, ему даже не обязательно иметь публичных виртуальных функций (ну, кроме деструктора, если нужно полиморфное удаление). Пример такого интерфейса - паттерн [NVI](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).

При желании более соответствовать ООП парадигме языков C#/Java можно давать интерфейсным классам имена, начинающиеся с буквы `I`, или даже добавить

```
#define interface struct
```

чтобы выделить интерфейсный класс при объявлении/определении. Такие подходы используются в MS COM.

Но в общем случае, этого не требуется, а проблему ромбовидной иерархии можно решить через виртуальное наследование.